# Updated Android Google Maps V2 limits

Tags: android, maps

I know that this question is already asked but I think that the limits are changed.

I developed an Android app that uses Google Maps V2 API. I will upload the app for free on Play Store but the users will pay from PayPal to my site for some services. There are links in my app that help the user go to my web site (via browser) and register.

After some research I am confused about the limits of requests of Google maps on Android. Are they free now?

Comment: Are free with limit usage. 25000 maps per day. https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Comment: Android and ios has no limits

Answer (score 2):

**// as mentioned on https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits**

The Maps API usage limits apply only to the following Maps API services:

- Google Maps JavaScript API v3
- Google Static Maps API
- Google Street View Image API

The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits.

and for Geocoding API 
the Google says

> If you are geocoding data in response to user input on the web, or on
>   a mobile device, then you dont have to worry about your quota.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client